# Using a UDF based on a group of keys in order to build a new column using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following `df` DataFrame:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- contractId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- profile: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- profileId: string (nullable = true)

df.show()
+---------------+--------+-----+---------------+
|code|contractId| profile|   id|      profileId|
+---------------+--------+-----+---------------+
|   A|        45|       S|  753|           true|
|   A|        45|       C|  451|           true|
|   C|         8|       S| null|          false|
|   C|         8|       C|  741|           true|
|   D|         1|       S|    7|           true|
|   D|         1|       C| null|          false|
+-----------------+------+-----+---------------+
```

I would like to change the content of the `profileId` column based on a grouping of the `code` and `contractId` primary keys and the values of the `profile` and `id` columns. So, the condition to be respected is the following:

```
if(col("profile") === "S" && col("id") != null) true // for all rows with the same value of 'code' and 'contractId' tuple
else false
```

So the result would be the following:

```
resultDf.show()
+---------------+--------+-----+----------+
|code|contractId| profile|   id| profileId|
+---------------+--------+-----+----------+
|   A|        45|       S|  753|      true|
|   A|        45|       C|  451|      true|
|   C|         8|       S| null|     false|
|   C|         8|       C|  741|     false| // changed from 'true' to 'false'
|   D|         1|       S|    7|      true|
|   D|         1|       C| null|      true| // changed from 'false' to 'true'
+-----------------+------+-----+----------+
```

Do you have an idea to build this type of algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the partition function.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.withColumn('profileId', f.expr("count(if(profile = 'S' and id is not null, true, null)) over (partition by code, contractId) > 0")) \
  .show()

+----+----------+-------+----+---------+
|code|contractId|profile|  id|profileId|
+----+----------+-------+----+---------+
|   A|        45|      S| 753|     true|
|   A|        45|      C| 451|     true|
|   C|         8|      S|null|    false|
|   C|         8|      C| 741|    false|
|   D|         1|      S|   7|     true|
|   D|         1|      C|null|     true|
+----+----------+-------+----+---------+
```